# javascript funcion árbol útopico

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Los árboles utópicos crecen de una forma particular, en dos ciclos:

```
Cada primavera duplican su tamaño
Cada verano crecen un metro
```

Si Laura planta un árbol utópico de un metro, al fin del otoño, ¿cuánto medirá de alto después de N ciclos?

Algunos ejemplos:

```
Si N = 0, su altura será 1 metro (no creció nada)
Si N = 1, su altura será de 2 metros (duplicó su altura en primavera)
Si N = 2, su altura será de 3 metros (creció un metro más en verano)
Si N = 3, su altura será de 6 metros (duplicó su altura en la siguiente primavera)
y así ...

Escribí la función alturaArbolUtopico, que tome una cantidad de ciclos de crecimiento, y devuelva la altura resultante del árbol de Laura.
```

Y realicé este código pero me da error: expected 1 to equal 2
Creo que lo estoy planteando mal.

```js
function alturaArbolUtopico(ciclos){
  var alto = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <ciclos; i ++){
    alto = i +1;
    alto = i *2 +1;
}
return alto;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué haces siempre la operación `alto = i *2 +1;` ?

Comment: Hola. Porque dice que cada primavera duplica el tamaño y en verano crece 1 metro

Comment: Peeeero, si el ciclo es uno impar, habrá crecido +1 un número de veces (digamos, X) y habrá duplicado su tamaño un número menor (exactamente X-1). Si es un ciclo par, esos dos valores serán iguales. Eso es lo raro en tu código: siempre le aumentas uno Y lo duplicas (+1, no sé por qué) para cada ciclo. Digamos que es ciclo 3... en el ciclo 1 ya subió uno y se duplicó, en el 2 igual... en el 3 otra vez. ¿Se entiende?

Comment: Si. Tiene razón. Ya lo modifiqué. Es así: function alturaArbolUtopico(ciclos){
  var resultado = 1;
  for(var i=1; i<=ciclos; i++){
    if(i%2===0){
      resultado++;
    } else {
      resultado = resultado*2;
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo en el caso que el número sea diferente de 0 e impar debe multiplicarse por 2 y en el caso de ser par debe ser el mismo más 1, quiza te funcione asi:

```js
function arbolutopico(ciclos) {
  
  var ciclos = ciclos;
  var altura = 1;
  
  if (ciclos == 0) {
    altura = 1;
  } 
  
  else
    {
      for (var i = 1; i<=ciclos; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0) {
        altura = (ciclos + 1);  
  }
  else {
      altura = ciclos * 2;
      
  }
        
      }
    }
  console.log (altura);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude modificar. Era así:

```js
function alturaArbolUtopico(ciclos){
  var resultado = 1;
  for(var i=1; i<=ciclos; i++){
    if(i%2===0){
      resultado++;
    } else {
      resultado = resultado*2;
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Ten cuidado porque estas evaluando el acumulador en el IF, imagina que ingresas un 5, entonces al iniciar el ciclo i valdrá 1, no entrará en el if, en el segundo recorrido i valdrá 2 entonces ahi si entrara y así sucesivamente, entonces te dará un resultado que no corresponde. Saludos